# Remove Banner from Attachments, and specific page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function that will add a banner ad to my page:

```
<?PHP tfuse_top_adds();?>
```

Now, I have tried to place to this banner on all pages, except attachments, and a specific page ID.  When I add the code:

```
<?PHP if(!is_attachment()) {tfuse_top_adds();} ?>
```

all is well, no ad on the attachment pages.  When I add the code:

```
<?PHP if(!is_page( 9000 )) {tfuse_top_adds();} ?>
```

all is well, no ad on page 9000.  However, when I try to combine the two conditions:

```
<?PHP if(!is_attachment() || !is_page( 9000 )) {tfuse_top_adds();} ?>
```

the ads are not removed from the page, or the attachement.  Ive tried a few iterations here too, and can't seem to hack it.  Any suggestions on how to write this statement is appreciated.

Comment: Read up in DeMorgan's law: !(a or b) == (!a and !b): Try `if(!((is_attachment() || is_page( 9000 )))`

Answer (score 1):

You need an `and`, not an `or`.

```
<?PHP if(!is_attachment() && !is_page( 9000 )) {tfuse_top_adds();} ?>
```

With your current code, one of `!is_attachment()` and `!is_page(9000)` will always be true, and with an `or`, that means the whole statement evaluates to true.